# Html load plaintext mime css file

Tags: html

I trying to load a css library from github (not uploading to my server due limited bandwidth)
It keeps saying strict mime checking stuff is theres any workaround that i can get this working, without using any bandwidth from my server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking for is CDN, github in it self is not a cdn and by design responds with plain text mime type which is why you getting errors etc. On top of that if you get frequent plain text request hits on repository then github takes it as something other then intended is going on and begins flagging things.

some cdn netwroks will allow you to turn github repo into cdn, they fetch and store code base on their server behind the scene.

Example (which I often use):

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/{username}/{repo}/
```

It will save your server bandwidth and also turn any github repo into cdn with adjusted mime type. Do keep on mind though since it would cached at CDN if you are making frequent changes to library they might not be updated in real time time lag could be anywhere from 5 minutes to 48 hours. You dont have control over this.

Secondly, now days if you use your headers right resources are vigorously cached by browsers (you have to work in it though) hence why we use hard refresh to purge/update cache.