# Php Sql making select statement case insensitive

Tags: mysql, sql

So i basically trying to check if username exists or not
but problem is people impersonating others by changing capitalazation
I need prevent that i read some answers but they for "LIKE" operator in sql not the

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE nick=? LIMIT 1
```

Ho i can make this return true on different capitilization too
Example: test exist on database
but if users try to register teST it should return it exists
or tEsT

[Database]

[image: 1]

I tried doing this:

```
$user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE nick COLLATE utf8_bin = ? LIMIT 1";
$dts = $db->prepare($user_check_query);
$dts->bind_param('s', $nick);
$dts->execute();
```

It still does not help.

Comment: tag your dbms , also provide sample data and desired output,

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67635789/html-load-plaintext-mime-css-file

Answer (score 1):

Try with a binary collation:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM users 
  WHERE username COLLATE utf8_bin = 'NicK'
```

Comment: cant i use prepared statement there?

Comment: Yes, why not..?

Comment: i tried but does not work still     `$user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE nick COLLATE utf8_bin = ? LIMIT 1";
 $dts = $db->prepare($user_check_query);
    $dts->bind_param('s', $nick);
    $dts->execute();`

Comment: can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

if your column is already has collation that is not case sensitive , then the query should be ok, if it is case sensitive you can change your query

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE lower(username) =lower('nick') LIMIT 1
```

but to stop that you need to make a unique constraint on that column:

```
alter table users 
add constraint unique_usernames UNIQUE (username)
```

considering collation is not case sensitive .

Comment: i using prepared statements using mysqli place to put "placeholder" on the query?

Comment: ok fixed it by `SELECT * FROM users WHERE lower(nick) =lower(?) LIMIT 1`

Comment: actually not helped after doing that fix i thought its fixed but still someone can make accounts like that

Comment: @bruhhy15 what do you mean it doesn't work

Comment: simply it finds case insensitive.

Comment: SELECT * FROM users WHERE lower(nick) =lower(?) LIMIT 1 using prepared statements

Comment: this is not example , show us some sample data and desired output

Comment: data = "usertest" db has usertest account desired output is failing and telling user account exists